# Find/replace string between HTML tags in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

Say I have the following code:

```
<div>
    Some text
    <h1>A divider</h1>
    More text
</div>
```

[Preferably] via jQuery, how would I grab "More text" and replace it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery doesn't really support textnodes that well, but native JS like nextSibling do :

```js
$('div h1').get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue = 'New text';
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uBKBk/)

Comment: i didnot know that you can grab the text outside of a tag,

Comment: This wouldn't preserve whitespace before or after the "More text" (which may or may not be important)

Comment: @Ian - no it wouldn't, but nothing really will, except something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uBKBk/1/) ?

Comment: (I had already upvoted your answer) I just wanted to point it out. Again, not sure how important it is to preserve the whitespace (in case it was in a `<pre>` or had CSS `white-space: pre;` or something similar), but yeah, I think the `.replace()` is more appropriate. That was all :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `.contents()`, you can look at child text nodes, then use `String.prototype.replace` to replace that text. Something like:

```
$("div").contents().each(function () {
    if (this.nodeType === 3) {
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace("More text", "Some new text");
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/uYJzM/

It's a pretty loose check for "More text", because it really depends on exactly what you want to do.

References:

- `.contents()`: http://api.jquery.com/contents/
- `.nodeType`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a `span` tag and use jQuery's [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method:

```
$("div").children("span").text("Whatever text you want");
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Wbh5Z/).

Comment: I am creating a user script and am unable to wrap that text with a span. Otherwise, great idea.